# Emit python list in Signal to Qml ui

Tags: python, qml, pyside6

I am trying to communicate a python script to a qml ui using signal/slot and, while it works for some types (str) it seems to not be working when I try emitting a list:

**Python:**

```
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, Signal, Slot
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
import time, sys

class PythonSignalEmitter(QObject):
    
    getListTest = Signal(list)
    @Slot()
    def callList(self):
        print("HELLO from python ")
        test = ["a", "b", "c"]
        self.getListTest.emit(test)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QGuiApplication([])
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    signal_emitter = PythonSignalEmitter()

    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("signalEmitter", signal_emitter)
    engine.load("main.qml")
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**Fragment of the main.qml file:**

```
Connections {
        target: signalEmitter
        function onSignal(res) {
            console.log(`------------`);
            console.log(`qml list is ${res}`);
            console.log(`------------`);    
        }
    }
```

The output of this just gives:

```
HELLO from python
```

So the app runs with no problem, and after a click on a specified component, the slot is called, but the log in the QLM side is not even printed, seems like the signal is not even emitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT]

You need to rename `onSignal` with `onGetListTest`. The rest is fine.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Window

ApplicationWindow {
    id: main
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Frame {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        RowLayout {
            Button {
                text: qsTr("Quit")
                onClicked: Qt.callLater(Qt.quit)
            }
            Button {
                text: qsTr("Test")
                onClicked: signalEmitter.callList()
            }
        }
    }

    Connections {
        target: signalEmitter
        function onGetListTest(res) {
            console.log(`------------`);
            console.log(`qml list is ${res}`);
            console.log(`------------`);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this has nothing to do with the problem...even if the log on the qml side was wrong....still it should print at least something...weird or not but at least something, see that not even the console.log with only ------- is being printed in qml side

Comment: Rewrote answer.

Comment: oh yes! that did the trick you are absolutely right...the name of the function on the qml side was the problem, 1000 thanks mate!